# How to calculate the asymptotic running time of a power of a number by repeated addition?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

```
function calculatePower(k,n) {
var power = 1;
for(var i =0;i<n;i++) {
    var tempPower = 0;
    for(var j=0; j<k;j++) {
        for(var q=0; q<power; q++) {
            tempPower++;
        }
    }
    power = tempPower;
}
return power;
}
calculatePower(2,3);
```

How would I calculate the running time for something like this? Would it be something in the lines of O(k+k^2+....+k^n) or O(k^n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `tempPower` will be initiated to `0` in each iteration over `i`, it would be equal `k*power` for each iteration. Hence, `power = k*power` and the time complexity of the code would be `T(k,n) = k + k^2 + k^3 + ... + k^n = k^{n+1} - 2 = Theta(k^{n+1})`.